# Getting error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

How do I fix this error? The user test function needs to hold the inputs for a string and a character, these inputs then need to be called in the reverse and character count functions.

```
def user_test():
    '''
    :return: hold user input
    '''
    global user_string
    global user_character
    user_string = print(input("What is the string you would like to use:"))
    user_character = print(input("What is the character you would like to use:"))
    character_count(user_string, user_character)
    reverse(user_string)
    return user_string, user_character;

def reverse(user_string):
    '''
    :param: string
    :return: reverses a string
    '''
    string = user_string
    print (list(reversed(string)))
    return string

def character_count(user_string, user_character):
    '''
    :return: counts the number of occurances of a character in a string
    '''
    string = user_string
    toCount = user_character
    counter = 0

    for letter in string:
            if( letter == toCount):
                    counter += 1
    print(counter)

def main():
    user_test()


main()
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cheryl\Documents\Python Stuff\lab6_design.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Cheryl\Documents\Python Stuff\lab6_design.py", line 108, in main
    user_test()
  File "C:\Users\Cheryl\Documents\Python Stuff\lab6_design.py", line 9, in user_test
    character_count(user_string, user_character)

  File "C:\Users\Cheryl\Documents\Python Stuff\lab6_design.py", line 34, in character_count
for letter in string:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `print(input("What is the string you would like to use:"))` print does not return a value so `user_string` is None

Answer (score 1):

print() returns None so user_string and user_character are None.

```
user_string = print(input("What is the string you would like to use:"))
user_character = print(input("What is the character you would like to use:"))
```

Change it to the following if you still want to print the input

```
user_string = input("What is the string you would like to use:")
print(user_string)
user_character = input("What is the character you would like to use:")
print(user_character)
```